# How to use CSS 'target' selector inline within HTML markup?

Tags: html, css

I would like to show/hide divs content on click with CSS only.
I can achieve so with below code but what I need to do is to place the CSS 'target' selector **inline**. I'll appreciate any help. Thx

```
<style>
.openDiv {display: none;}
.openDiv:target {display: block;}
</style>
<ul>
<li><a href="#Expando1">The Tick</a>
<ul class="openDiv" id="Expando1">
<li>Has superhuman strength and mass;</li>
<li>Is nigh-invulnerable; </li>
<li>Has powers that increase as the situation becomes more dramatic;</li>
<li>Does not seem to require oxygen;</li>
<li>Cannot keep his balance if his antennae are removed.</li>
</ul>    
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't ...selectors can't be **inline**...only styles. You'll have to rethink. Perhaps the "checkbox hack"?

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] ~ ul {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="expando" id="expando" />
    <label for="expando">The Tick</label>
    <ul class="openDiv" id="openDiv1">
      <li>Has superhuman strength and mass;</li>
      <li>Is nigh-invulnerable;</li>
      <li>Has powers that increase as the situation becomes more dramatic;</li>
      <li>Does not seem to require oxygen;</li>
      <li>Cannot keep his balance if his antennae are removed.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```